# CakePHP - sending POST requests in cakephp API and data handling

Tags: php, json, api, post, cakephp-2.0

I have created a CakePHP app and after already set the routes.php files,i can send JSON requests,in order to use my app as an API. For testing,i have created a function which goes like this:

```
public function api() {
    if($this->request->is('post')) {
        $data1 = (string)$this->request->data['Model']['data1'];
        $data2 = (string)$this->request->data['Model']['data2'];

        //logic goes here,it does stuff and $result is the variable where the result of the login is saved
        //$data1 and $data2 are used in the logic

        $result = 'result';
        $this->set('results',$result);
        $this->set('_serialize',array('results'));
    }

}
```

I have also created the exact same function with another name,which is meant to be used via a web form and that works correctly. BUT,this code,at this function here,when i POST data (i use Dev HTTP Client chrome extension),it returns the $results variable empty,like it does not receive what i send :/
I send the data as follows via the chrome extension i use:

```
data1='stuff1'&data2='stuff2'
```

and it returns me just

```
{
"results":""
}
```

(while the same code works perfectly when used without json).

Did i miss something?Does it seem to do something wrong? Please help me a bit around here..

ps:if you need more info,just tell me and i'll post it.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to access that post would be

```
$this->request->data['data1'];
```

to verify what data is being sent do this:

```
public function api() {
    //if($this->request->is('post')) {
        $data1 = (string)$this->request->data['Model']['data1'];
        $data2 = (string)$this->request->data['Model']['data2'];

        //logic goes here,it does stuff and $result is the variable where the result of the login is saved
        //$data1 and $data2 are used in the logic

        $result = 'result';
        //$this->set('results',$result);
        $this->set('results',array('root'=>$this->request);
        $this->set('_serialize',array('results'));
    //}
}
```

Comment: the changes i made will allow you to see all of the request object as a json string. you will be able to verify how the data is passed.

Comment: Yes,it returned me this:
{"results":{"root":{"params":{"plugin":null,"controller":"mails","action":"api","named":[],"pass":[],"ext":"json","isAjax":false,"models":{"User":{"plugin":null,"className":"User"}}},"data":null,"query":[],"url":"mails\/api.json","base":"","webroot":"\/","here":"\/mails\/api.json"}}}
As you can see,the "data" array is empty(null),thus none of my data is received from cakePHP. Why this is happening? :/

Comment: looks like the issue could be at the javascript level. lets take a look at that. but link to a pastebin please :-)

Comment: i've not created any JS till now,i just test my api through Dev HTTP client,the chrome extension..isn't it right? :/